# Java program is not able to write complete web content, however in SOAPUI, I can see complete content

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest

I wrote a Java program to make a simple HTTP get call and read content from a REST webservice. I include 2 custom HTTP headers and provide values to them.

In SOAPUI, when I make a REST call with updating those 2 headers, I get proper response, however when I make the same call in my Java program, I get truncated output. Below is my code:

```
    try {
         URL url = new URL(lnk);
         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
         connection.setRequestProperty("HeaderParameter1", param1);
         connection.setRequestProperty("HeaderParamter2", param2);
         connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
         
         InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
         byte [] b = new byte [is.available()];
         is.read(b);
         String input = new String(b);
         System.out.println("The payload is \n"+input);
         connection.disconnect();} catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: You should iterate around available() and read until available returns -1.

Comment: Hi Anders, Thanks for the reply. I tried using IOUtils.toString(inputStream) method to read the data and now I'm able to complete data. I tried to upvote your comment and an answer below but looks like I dont have the rights to do so. Kindly consider my reply as thank you from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `is.available()` returns the number of bytes that are available to be read without blocking, but that may be less than the full content of the response. In the [documentation for this method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available()), it says: "It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream."

A simple way to read the entire response into a `String` could be:

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
byte [] b = is.readAllBytes();
String input = new String(b);
```

There are two caveats with this approach:

1. The [`new String(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)) constructor uses the platform's default charset to convert the bytes to characters. This is generally not a good idea for network protocols, since the client and server need to agree on the character encoding. You can hardcode the charset encoding if it will always be the same, for example: `new String(b, "UTF-8")`.
2. If the response is very large, this will allocate a large byte array. If your handling of the response can be written in a streaming manner, it would be better to read iteratively with a fixed buffer size, as Anders mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the reply. I very much appreciate that. readAllBytes() is available from Java 9 onwards and we are supposed to use Java8. So please let me know if there is any other alternative.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, I meant to mention that. There are other ways to read all of the bytes into an array,  but as I mentioned in my answer, this is probably not what you want to do in a real application. If you can update your question to talk about what you really want to do with the response, I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I get XML data as the response, and I wanted that XML data saved into an XML file. I ended up reading the input stream by converting that into a string using IOUtils.toString(inputStream) method. This worked, however the performance is not that great. It took more than 6 minutes to get complete data. Anyways thanks for the replies Tim. This made me realize I still have a lot to learn in Core Java. :)

Comment: @AjeyaGubbiVaani glad that you got it working! As I mentioned, reading the entire response at once is not the most efficient option. This is true whether you're reading it into a `String` or a byte array. Since you're using Apache Commons IO, try `FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, file)` https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyInputStreamToFile-java.io.InputStream-java.io.File-

Comment: I will be running this program in another application, (SAP PI/PO actually), so the option of writing contents into a file is prohibited (even if temporarily) in PRD live environment.

Comment: @AjeyaGubbiVaani if you'll be using an XML parsing library to process the response, most of them will accept an `InputStream` directly.